# How to fix EFI_DEVICE_ERROR

Tags: c++, driver, uefi

I'm trying to use http protocol in UEFI. I've seen the example on the page 1539 UEFI_Spec, but when I'm trying to make HttpProtocol->Reqest() I get EFI_DEVICE_ERROR. Where can be the problem? Picking the code below.

```
//...
//UPD
ConfigData.HttpVersion = HttpVersion11;
ConfigData.TimeOutMillisec = 0; // Indicates default timeout period
ConfigData.LocalAddressIsIPv6 = FALSE; 
ZeroMem(&IPv4Node, sizeof(IPv4Node));
IPv4Node.UseDefaultAddress = TRUE; // Obtain IP address from DHCP
ConfigData.AccessPoint.IPv4Node = &IPv4Node;
Status = HttpProtocol->Configure(HttpProtocol, &ConfigData);


RequestData.Method = HttpMethodGet;
RequestData.Url = L"https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/UX303UA/UX303UAAS303.zip"
RequestHeader.FieldName = "Host";
RequestHeader.FieldValue = "443";  
RequestMessage.Data.Request = &RequestData;
RequestMessage.HeaderCount = 1;
RequestMessage.Headers = &RequestHeader;
RequestMessage.BodyLength = 0;
RequestMessage.Body = NULL;
RequestToken.Event = NULL;
Status = gBS->CreateEvent( EVT_NOTIFY_SIGNAL, TPL_CALLBACK, RequestCallback, NULL, &RequestToken.Event);
if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
{
   return Status;
}
gST->ConOut->OutputString(gST->ConOut, DebCE);


RequestToken.Status = EFI_SUCCESS;
RequestToken.Message = &RequestMessage;
gRequestCallbackComplete = FALSE;
// Finally, make HTTP request.

Status = HttpProtocol->Request(HttpProtocol, &RequestToken);
if(EFI_ERROR(Status))
{
    return Status;
}
```

Comment: Have you initialized a network device?  An IP address?  A default route?

Comment: Yes, I’m using QEMU VM and qemu-ifup script.

Comment: So does `ping` work?

Comment: You are making a https request, is the TLS driver loaded and configured?

Comment: I've switched to on. Now I've got EFI_NO_MAPPING.

Comment: I've updated the code to show my ConfigData.

Comment: EFI_NO_MAPPING sounds like a dns problem, check if the DnsDxe Driver is loaded. Try it with a http call https is more complex, it requires the TlsDxe Driver to be loaded and configured (CA list, Ciphers).
The value of the host header should not be the port, it should be the server name ("dlcdnets.asus.com" in your example)

Comment: @MiSimon: I've cheked the DnsDxe, using shell comand "drivers", it's ok. And I've tryed it with http, it also gives me EFI_NO_MAPPING.

Comment: @MiSimon: I've tryed to make "ifconfig -s eht0 dhcp". And then load my driver and it gave me EFI_TIMEOUT. Why my IP in driver is not obtaining from DHCP? It not gives error. And how can I do it in code of my driver?

Comment: Can you upload you complete code and give some more information about your environment?

Comment: @MiSimon: I did not configured the network correctly (when my ovmf is up i got no IP). I tried through the shell to get an IP using DHCP and everything worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could write a short answer describing which shell commands you used and accept it as answer, this way others can find your solution.

Comment: To obtain IP from DHCP you should write in shell "ifconfig -s eth0 dhcp".